# Gradle tasks log during run build apps

Tags: android, gradle

I build my `Android` app using `Gradle` as build system. There is some `idea` run/debug configurations that I can run. What's interesting for me is the debug configuration of my android app and `gradle` run tasks configurations.

When I start gradle configuration for executing, I can see in run window all outputs and logs of gradle tasks running at that moment. But when I start my Android app debug configuration, I do not see any gradle tasks output at all. But I know that some of its steel run before compiling java source code.

Is there is any setting or options that I can add to always show gradle tasks output, when I start Android ap run configuration? Thanks a lot!